# Building An RTP Server in iOS That Allows WiFi Speakers To Stream Music

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, rtp

***A Little Background On Why I Have To Do This***

I am currently optimising an app in order to improve the transferring of media files to the WiFi speakers that our team developed. Our solution before was using iPhone as an HTTP server and then allow the speakers to connect and download music from it. But unfortunately a lot of problems occurred such as frequent slow transfer speed, file read failure, and when user uses the "seek" command, the speakers would have to download the whole file in order for it to seek into that particular time before it starts to play. This is a very bad experience for our users.

***What I Need***

In order to solve the problem I mentioned above. We thought of changing the HTTP server to an RTP server that will be ran on an iPhone and then allows the WiFi speakers to stream music from it. However, from what I read on other Q&A platforms they mentioned that iPhone does that support transferring of data using RTP. I also tried searching here in stack but were not able to find an answer that solves my problem.

***My Question***

Is it possible to run an RTP server on iPhone and is there any demo about this that I can refer to?

Any suggestions would be high appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read link http://dss.macosforge.org/ 
Darwin Streaming Server from Apple official.

However, I'm not sure it can work on iOS.

Best regards,

Comment: Have a look this link hopefully it can help you .http://research.edm.uhasselt.be/~jori/page/index.php?n=CS.Jrtplib